# JQuery mobile dynamic split button list view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm new in jquery mobile. I'm trying to do a dynamic split button list view.
The first button is working fine that means when it is clicked, the item list name is passed to the "gotoQuantity(this)" function. However, the second button is not working. That is the list view name is not being passed to  "deleteItemFromList(this)" function.

Please how can I solve this problem?

Html:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true" id = itemsList data-split-icon="delete">
</ul>
```

Script:

```
function loadMainList() {
    //loads main items list
    $("#itemsList").empty();
    for (var key in mainList) {
        itemToList = key;

        $('#itemsList').append('<li><a onclick="gotoQuantity(this)">' + itemToList + '</a><a onclick="deleteItemFromList(this)">' + itemToList + '</a></li>');
    };
    $("#itemsList").listview('refresh');
}

function gotoQuantity(obj) {
    alert($(obj).text());
}

function deleteItemFromList(obj) {   //deletes item from main list
    alert($("#itemsList").text());
}
```

Comment: Do not use `onclick` event handlers, add a `gotoQuantity` class to the tag and use `$(document).on("click", ".gotoQuantity", function() { alert("click");}`

Comment: My problem is that a need to pass the parameter which is the <li> name to the function deleteItemFromList(this).  It is working for the gotoQuantity function.

Comment: Use an attribute or `$(this).parent()` inside event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When jQuery Mobile enhances the list, the split button text is removed and then added as the title attribute of the anchor.  So your quick fix would be

```
function deleteItemFromList(obj) {   //deletes item from main list
    alert($(obj).prop('title'));
}
```

However, i would take SGA's approach from the comments and make the item id a data attribute of the LI and then use event delegation to create the handlers and retrieve the id:

```
$("#itemsList").empty();
for (var i=0; i<mainList.length; i++) {
    itemToList = mainList[i];
    $('#itemsList').append('<li data-id="' + itemToList + '"><a href="#" class="goQuant">' + itemToList + '</a><a href="#" class="deleteItem">' + itemToList + '</a></li>');
};
$("#itemsList").listview('refresh');

$("#itemsList").on("click", ".goQuant", function(){
  alert($(this).parent("li").jqmData("id"));
});
$("#itemsList").on("click", ".deleteItem", function(){
  alert($(this).parent("li").jqmData("id"));
});
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/pNVQLd)**